Ratio of variance to sum of squared differences between consecutive elements
This is something that I thought would be a relatively straightforward problem, but it has been far harder than anticipated.
Given a finite list of real numbers $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$, I have been trying to figure out how to minimize the ratio between two quantities.
One quantity $s=(x_2-x_1)^2+...+(x_n-x_{n-1})^2$ is the sum of squares of differences between consecutive elements in the list.
The other quantity is the sum of squared deviations by the mean (which is proportional to the variance for constant $n$): Given mean $\bar{x}$, this quantity is $t=\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\bar{x})^2$.
It is clear that, to minimize $s/t$, the $x_i$'s must be in sorted order.  One approach would be to have the $x_i$'s be an arithmetic sequence, which gives $s/t=\frac{12}{n(n+1)}$.  Call this ratio $s_0/t_0$.
For $n\leq 3$, this is optimal.  As $n$ increases, fixing $x_1=-1$ and $x_n=1$, the values of intermediate $x_i$'s in the list can be given as roots of $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$-degree polynomials.  Using this, one can calculate that, for $n=4$, the minimum possible $s/t$ is $1-10\left(\frac{3-2\sqrt{2}}{6-3\sqrt{2}}\right)\approx 2.4\%$ lower than $s_0/t_0$.  For $n=5$, the optimum is $1-\frac{20}{8\phi^2}\approx 4.5\%$ lower.  However, the for $n=6$ and $n=7$, the corresponding cubic polynomials have incredibly messy solutions according to Wolfram Alpha, and it becomes extremely difficult to solve analytically.
Running simulations suggests that, as $n$ grows, the minimum value of $s/t$ converges to approximately $17.5\%$ lower than $s_0/t_0$.  However, I haven't been able to prove this.  Does anyone know about this convergence?
